# What is the simplest query in SQL to get the differences between 2 tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Have 2 tables with a column `Country` and I'm trying to get the results one for the same countries in both, one for countries in the first table but not in the second, and one for countries in second table but not in the first.

`Tb1.Country`:

```
Botswana
Burkina Faso
Cameroon
Ethiopia
Ghana
Ghana
Ghana
Ghana
Ghana
Morocco
Nigeria
Nigeria
Nigeria
Sierra Leone
South Africa
South Africa
South Africa
South Africa
South Africa
South Africa
Tanzania
Zambia
India
India
India
India
Indonesia
Pakistan
Pakistan
Pakistan
Philippines
Thailand
Thailand
```

`TB2.Country`:

```
Angola
Botswana
Burkina Faso
Ethiopia
Ghana
Ghana
Ghana
Morocco
Nigeria
Nigeria
Nigeria
Rwanda
Sierra Leone
South Africa
South Africa
Tanzania
Zambia
India
India
Indonesia
Pakistan
Pakistan
Philippines
Sri Lanka
Thailand
Thailand
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to get all the countries which are in both tables

Comment: @ubaidashrafmasoody no use the INNER JOIN to get the countries in both and NOT EXISTS to get the country in one table but not the other!

Comment: I'd vote up the question, as it is a common issue developers face, but Steve's right, it needs to have things that have been tried and failed.  I actually tried `NOT IN` in Oracle before Googling this and that failed dismally (`SQL command not properly ended`).  `NOT EXISTS` I think is a SQL version of that and doesn't compile in Oracle.  I believe `INNER JOIN` is the opposite of what the OP wanted (and opposite of what I needed, too), but a good conversation starter in order to define what the output should actually be.  `MINUS` is what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a UNION query to do this in Access:

```
SELECT
    TB1.Country,
    "Country in Table 1, but not Table 2" as result
FROM
    tb1 
    LEFT JOIN tb2 ON
        tb1.country = tb2.country
WHERE tb2.country IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT
    TB2.Country,
    "Country in Table 2, but not Table 1"
FROM
    tb2 
    LEFT JOIN tb1 ON
        tb2.country = tb1.country
WHERE tb1.country IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT
    TB2.Country,
    "Country is in both tables"
FROM
    tb2 
    INNER JOIN tb1 ON
        tb2.country = tb1.country
```

That's three queries that are stuck together with a union. The first finds countries in table 1 that aren't in Table 2. The second finds countries in table 2 that aren't in table 1, and the final query only returns countries that are in both.

Comment: Thanx JN, gives me syntax error  "Country in Table 1, but not Table 2" as result, missing operator

Comment: I think I forgot some commas in there. Just fixed.

Comment: Change the UNION ALL's to UNION and it will GROUP BY both columns returned.

Comment: Works great, just added at the end

Comment: when i run them 1 by one working fine when i run them all togeather with UNION i get Syntax Error JOIN.

Comment: JN please the last one, how can i add an Where another field in both tables is DEC13 >0?

Comment: Think of each bit seperated by the `UNION ALL` as a stand alone statement. In the last one you can add `WHERE [tb1].[DEC13] > 0 and [tb2].[DEC13] > 0` and it should filter the way you want.

Comment: anything im doing wrong here?                                                                            SELECT Tb1.Country, 
FROM Tb1
LEFT JOIN Tb1.Dc14 ON
           Tb1.Dc13 = Tb.Dc14
WHERE Tb1.Dc14 IS NULL AND WHERE  (((Tb1.Dc13)>0) AND ((Tb1.Dc14)>0))
GROUP BY Tb1.Country;

Comment: Yep. You can only have a single WHERE clause in a SELECT statement: `SELECT Tb1.Country, FROM Tb1 LEFT JOIN Tb1.Dc14 ON Tb1.Dc13 = Tb.Dc14 WHERE Tb1.Dc14 IS NULL AND Tb1.Dc13>0 AND Tb1.Dc14>0 GROUP BY Tb1.Country;`  Which still won't return anything because TB1.DC14 can't be both NULL and greater than 0. You'll have to figure out what you really want there though.

Comment: Just trying to get the Countries that where removed or added based on values (>0) on De13 and De14.

Comment: Then you probably don't need the `Tb1.Dc14 IS NULL` bit in there. Remove that and you should be golden.

Comment: SELECT Tb.Country,
FROM Tb
LEFT JOIN Tb.Dc14 ON Tb.Dc13 = Tb.Dc14 
WHERE (((Tb.Dc13)>0) AND ((Tb.Dc14)>0)) 
GROUP BY Tb.Country;   Syntax Error

Comment: `SELECT Tb.Country FROM Tb LEFT JOIN Tb.Dc14 ON Tb.Dc13 = Tb.Dc14 WHERE Tb.Dc13>0 AND Tb.Dc14>0 GROUP BY Tb.Country;`  You had an extra comma hanging out after `Tb.Country`

Comment: sorry, im getting on your nerves, now I get JOIN expression not supported

Comment: JN with some help based on your logic, just a bit twist                                                                                                 SELECT "Dc13 Only" AS Status, Country
 FROM Tb1 AS T1
 WHERE Dc13 IS NOT NULL
 AND NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT *
      FROM Tb1 As T2
      WHERE T2.Country = T1.Country
       AND Dc14 IS NOT NULL)

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple set operations in Standard SQL, not only UNION, but also EXCEPT and INTERSECT.

Get the countries common in both tables:

```
select country from t1
intersect
select country from t2
```

Get the countries only in the first table:

```
select country from t1
except -- Oracle calls this MINUS
select country from t2
```

Change the order of the selects to get the countries in t2 not found in t1.

Comment: One note on the 2nd one (`MINUS` or `EXCEPT` table):  I found if you do this in the wrong order than you intend, it matters immensely.  You need to do the query that gives you the most results *first*, then do the query that gives you the fewer results set that you want to remove from the first table.  Doing it the other way around will give you an odd result.

Comment: @vapcguy: Of course, that's why I wrote *Get the countries only in the first table* and *Change the order of the selects to get the countries in t2 not found in t1*

Comment: @ dnoeth I can read and saw what you put, but that's exactly what wasn't clear to me and why I made my comment.  Saying to order the query by doing a 'get on one set that isn't in the other' isn't very specific, at all - it doesn't say what goes first or second, and your statement seemed to contradict the code above it.  Should've said to do the largest grouping *first*, minus the smaller set that chips away at the larger set.

Comment: @vapcguy: The first Select doesn't have to be on the larger set, it's on the one you want to remove the rows found in the 2nd. So the Except returns the rows only found in the 1st Select

Comment: @ dnoeth You're saying the same thing as what I did. If you have a grouping to remove rows from, that is the same thing as the larger set, and will always be a larger number, just like it will always be a smaller set of exclusions to take away from that group, and why those are 2nd and always need to be 2nd. Just like if you have 2 records in table #1, and want to exclude 1 record using a Select from table #2. 2 records - 1 record = 1. You should not try 1 record - 2 records and get -1 -- so order matters immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Union will do in your case:

Step1 ) This will give you countries in both the tables, duplicates won't be shown.

```
SELECT Country FROM Tb1
UNION
SELECT Country FROM Tb2
```

Step2) This will give you countries in first table but not in second:

```
Select  Country from Tb1
Where Country Not IN( 
Select Country from Tb2)
```

Step 3) This will give you countries in 2nd table but not in first

```
Select  Country from Tb2
Where Country Not IN( 
Select Country from Tb1)
```

Comment: Thank you, 33% answer :), now the other 2/3, to Get whats missing from Tb1, and whats missing from Tb2. Desired Result should be Cameroon Tb1 and Angola, Rwanda Sri Lanka Tb2

Comment: Check now @user3601458

Comment: Union All will give you duplicates also, so use UNION only @user3601458

Comment: Thank you Ubaid. JN was faster :)

Comment: When combining result tables, just give the queries above parenthesis and aliases, then do a `UNION` of the aliased tables.  The combining of results sets is easy.